# Find and remove duplicate items in a custom array type

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates, swift3

I have the following class, based on a node/key combo:

```
class cellData {
   let nodeText : String
   let keyText : String

   init(nodeText: String, keyText: String) {
      self.nodeText = nodeText
      self.keyText = keyText
   }

   var desription: String { return "<Node; name: \(nodeText); key; \(keyText)>" }
}
```

Based on the class above, I created two sets:

```
var firstSetData = [cellData]()
var secondSetData = [cellData]()

firstSetData = [cellData(nodeText: "a", keyText: "1"),
                cellData(nodeText: "a", keyText: "2"),
                cellData(nodeText: "c", keyText: "42")]

 secondSetData = [cellData(nodeText: "a", keyText: "1"),
                  cellData(nodeText: "b", keyText: "100"),
                  cellData(nodeText: "c", keyText: "2"),
                  cellData(nodeText: "d", keyText: "1")]
```

I need a function that will return a 3rd set of class "cellData", but with only one unique instance of the same node/key combo. That means my final set has to look like this:

```
finalSet = [cellData(nodeText: "a", keyText: "1"),
            cellData(nodeText: "a", keyText: "2"),
            cellData(nodeText: "b", keyText: "100"),
            cellData(nodeText: "c", keyText: "2"),
            cellData(nodeText: "c", keyText: "42")]        
            cellData(nodeText: "d", keyText: "1")]
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
for node in combinedSetData {
    if (combinedSetData.filter({$0.nodeText == node.nodeText && $0.keyText == node.keyText})).count > 1 {
     // remove duplicate elements and append to new set      
     }

 }
```

Swift 3 would be preferred if possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly doesn't 'quite work', what is the error? You could start by making your class `equatable`, this will make you able to use `==` to compare 2 class instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make your `cellData` class conforms to `Equatable`:

```
class cellData : Equatable { 
   static func ==(lhs: cellData, rhs: cellData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.nodeText == rhs.nodeText && lhs.keyText == rhs.keyText
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then building your `finalSetData` is easy:

```
var finalSetData = [cellData]()
(firstSetData + secondSetData).forEach {
    if !finalSetData.contains($0) {
        finalSetData.append($0)
    }
}

// To match the order in your example...
finalSetData.sort {
    if $0.nodeText != $1.nodeText {
        return $0.nodeText < $1.nodeText
    } else {
        return $0.keyText < $1.keyText
    }
}
```

A few other points:

- `desription` is misspelled
- You better conform the class to `CustomStringConvertible` too
- Follow Swift's naming convention. You will thank yourself later. Rename your class to `CellData`

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works now! Still learning and trying to get used to Swift's syntax and best practices. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Implement `Equatable` like Code Different says, but for building the "3rd" set you might want to actually use `Set`, like so:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [4,5,6,7]
let c = Set(a+b)   // {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1}
```

Sort the result, if needed.